# Activity feeds with rollups

Tags: neo4j

We have items in our app that form a tree-like structure. You might have a pattern like the following:

`(c:card)-[:child]->(subcard:card)-[:child]->(subsubcard:card) ... etc`

Every time an operation is performed on a card (at any level), we'd like to record it. Here are some possible events:

- The title of a card was updated by Bob
- A comment was added by Kate mentioning Joe
- The status of a card changed from pending to approved

The linked list approach seems popular but given the sorts of queries we'd like to perform, I'm not sure if it works the best for us.

Here are the main queries we will be running:

- All of the activity associated with a particular card AND child cards, sorted by time of the event (basically we'd like to merge all of these activity feeds together)
- All of the activity associated with a particular person sorted by time

On top of that we'd like to add filters like the following:

- Filter by person involved
- Filter by time period

It is also important to note that cards may be re-arranged very frequently. In other words, the parents may change.

Any ideas on how to best model something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions, but I would suggest benchmarking them.

The linked list approach might be good if you could use the Java APIs (perhaps via an unmanaged extension for Neo4j).  If the newest event in the list were the one attached to the card (and essentially the list was ordered by the date the events happened down the line), then if you're filtering by time you could terminate early when you've found an event which is earlier than the specified time.

Attaching the events directly to the card has the potential to lead you down into problems with supernodes/dense nodes.  It would be the simplest to query for in Cypher, though.  The problem is that Cypher will look at all of them before filtering.  You could perhaps improve the performance of queries by, in addition to placing the date/time of the event on the event node, placing it on the relationships to the node (`(:Card)-[:HAS_EVENT]->(:Event)` or `(:Event)-[:PERFORMED_BY]->(:Person)`).  Then when you query you can filter by the relationships so that it doesn't need to traverse to the nodes.

Regardless, it would probably be helpful to break up the query like so:

```
MATCH (c:Card {uuid: 'id_here')-[:child*0..]->(child:Card)
WITH child
MATCH (child)-[:HAS_EVENT]->(event:Event)
```

I *think* that would mean that the `MATCH` is going to have fewer permutations of paths that it will need to evaluate.

Others are welcome to supplement my dubious advice as I've never really dealt with supernodes personally, just read about them ;)

Comment: Thanks Brian :).Does Neo4j allow sorting by range indexes? For example, if I had event nodes timestamps, would I be able to efficiently query events that 1. fall within a certain time range and 2. belong to to the child?

Comment: Neo4j can definitely use indexes to do faster queries on ranges (starting in 2.3).  The trick is making sure that it can figure which is the most limiting place to start.  If you think that filtering by event dates is going to give you the smaller starting point then you might start by `MATCH`ing on events instead.